# Custom Pulumi destroy logic

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, infrastructure, pulumi

How do you use Pulumi to destroy resources like CloudFront distributions (which need to be disabled before they can be destroyed) that require other operations to be preformed before they can be removed. I cannot seem to find a way to add custom destroy logic to a Pulumi stack. Does anyone have experience doing this?

Comment: What happens when you try and do a normal pulumi destroy? If the provider is implemented correctly, it'll do a disable then poll for disabled status then do a delete I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot alter pulumi destroy logic as far as I know. Its not even in the code you write (its tied to resources in the stack, when you run pulumi destroy your code is not being called) so...